# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: quickfix/MessageFactory error when trying to run the Banzai application

Tags: quickfixj

I've cloned the quickfixj repo and I've been trying to run the Banzai application. I'm using intelliJ ultimate as the IDE.

I ran:
`mvn clean`
 `mvn compile package`
`java -jar target/quickfixj-examples-banzai-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

The first 2 commands run successfully, however, when running the last command from the terminal I get the following error:
`Error: Unable to initialize main class quickfix.examples.banzai.Banzai Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: quickfix/MessageFactory`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the build instructions here https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj#build-instructions and here https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj#importing-the-project-into-the-ide ?

Apart from that the `NoClassDefFoundError` originates from missing this class on the classpath. There are standalone JARs for the examples that should contain all needed classes. E.g. `quickfixj-examples-banzai-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`